# How can I pass the value of a checkbox from one page to another?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

I am trying to pass a selected checkbox value from one page to another to run a mysql statement on my db.
This is what I have:

**HTML**

```
<form method='POST' action='move_compaudit.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='checkbox' value='0'/>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='1'/>
```

**PHP** (this file called move_compaudit.php)

```
<?php
  include('include/dbConnection.php');
  $checkbox = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? 'Set' : 'NotSet';
  //SQL statement
  $query = "SELECT * FROM compaudit;";
  $results = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die('Error querying database');
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
  $query1 = "DELETE FROM compaudit WHERE serial_no = $row[7] AND $checkbox = 'Set'";    
  //Execute prepared MySQL statement
  //$results1 = mysqli_query($dbc,$query1) or die('Error querying database');
  print_r($query);
  print_r($query1);
?>
```

**My badly printed query**: I get this everytime, regardless of click or not clicked.

```
SELECT * FROM compaudit;DELETE FROM compaudit WHERE serial_no = 12345 AND Set = 'Set'
```

Comment: Is Set a column in the compaudit table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to keep your HTML as it is, you need to check the actual value of $_POST['checkbox'] instead of checking if it is set. Your hidden field guarantees that even if it is not checked, $_POST will still get a value for "checkbox".

```
<?php
include('include/dbConnection.php');
$checkbox = ($_POST['checkbox'] == '1') ? 'Set' : 'NotSet';
....
```

Comment: ZOMG THANK YOU BUNCHES! 

it was empty($_POST['checkbox']);  that I Missed

Answer (score 0):

`Set` is keyword in mysql :) you should escape it with `

Answer (score 0):

If you declare before the checkbox a hidden with same name, this variable will be forever true for isset.

Look to @GameBit tip, escape with backticks the fields and quote/escape all variables before use into a query.

Comment: So I changed to: 
        $checkbox = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? 'Clicked' : 'NotClicked';
Still it defaults to Clicked